# subscribe to feed in Android to receive by email

Tags: android, email, rss, subscription

I'm an android developer and I want to make it easy for my users to get news and updates about my apps, is there an API or a way for them to enter their email address in the app and receive updates to their email?

Right now I have a Google site, and the RSS feed subscription works through feedburner.

Thanks!

Edit: it's more to provide general information about upcoming things and possible new features.
The way it is now, I have an email form, and the person must send me an email to a specific address, then I check that inbox and manually keep a log of all the interested people.

Is there perhaps a way to embed the feedburner sign up mechanism into my app?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no standard interface for users to subscribe to feeds or emails about updates to applications. In more recent Android Markets (I think since 2.1-update1) Android Market can automatically notify the user about available updates to your app, but if you want to automatically email them updates then you will want to implement some sort of update transmission function in your app by yourself.